# Problem with WMS layer from SAGIS: Invalid format/can't parse XML

Tags: qgis, wms

Can you help me the following problem:
I try to load WMS layer from SAGIS (Salzburg GIS) into Qgis: 
http://www.salzburg.gv.at/themen/se/sagis/download.htm

for example: Geoland WMS

```
http://service.salzburg.gv.at/ArcGIS/services/Geoland_WMS_Land_Salzburg/MapServer/WMSServer
```

added "?version=1.1.1" to the url

connect

The dirctory of the availble layers appers

ID-0 - layers
ID-1 - Polygondecker
ID-3 - Orientierunskarte 
and so on till 
ID-41 - Landesgrenzen

chose the first directory: 0 - Layers (or any other, does not matter)

click "connect" (Hinzufügen)

following report appears:

```
Antwort: (<)?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
(<)!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.1.1/exception_1_1_1.dtd">
 (<)ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1">
 (<)ServiceException code="InvalidFormat">
Can't parse XML request.
 (<)/ServiceException>
(<)/ServiceExceptionReport>
```

edit: 
When I add the suggestion from Brad:

?request=getcapabilities&service=WMS&version=1.1.1&

still the same message as above appears

I expect to see the chosen layers, but i can only see it in the layer dialog. whenever doing a click on the layers (e.g. zoom to selected layer) the same error message as above appears.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service end point for the service is as below, you should use this as the URL you add to any client such as QGIS.

http://service.salzburg.gv.at/ArcGIS/services/Geoland_WMS_Land_Salzburg/MapServer/WMSServer?

To view the capabilities response from the service you would need to add the following parameters after the question mark:

- service=WMS&
- request=GetCapabilities&
- version=1.1.1&

Note:

- The version parameter is optional, without it the highest version of WMS supported by the service is returned. In this case the highest version is 1.3.0, so if you want a 1.1.1 version response you must explicitly mention it otherwise you can omit it.
- The parameter values (**WMS** and **GetCapabilities**) are according the WMS standard case sensitive, though for most servers you can spell them in any case...

So the GetCapabilities request becomes either:

Version 1.3.0: http://service.salzburg.gv.at/ArcGIS/services/Geoland_WMS_Land_Salzburg/MapServer/WMSServer?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&

or

Version 1.1.1: http://service.salzburg.gv.at/ArcGIS/services/Geoland_WMS_Land_Salzburg/MapServer/WMSServer?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&version=1.1.1&

Note:

If you click on these links you will note that the version 1.3.0 request will open in your browser, but the version 1.1.1 request will not, instead you will need to save it to disk.
This is because the two responses have different MIME types (the former is text/xml the latter is application/vnd.ogc.wms_xml).

So as I understand it the original problem you had was you used the the URL supplied by the website http://service.salzburg.gv.at/ArcGIS/services/Geoland_WMS_Land_Salzburg/MapServer/WMSServer?version=1.1.1 which is missing some of the required parameters if you want to browse to it (as with the GetCapabilities requests above).

I'm not sure how you're getting the second error after following the advice from [[BradHards]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/8563/bradhards) but my guess is you have probably ([duplicated one of the parameters](http://service.salzburg.gv.at/ArcGIS/services/Geoland_WMS_Land_Salzburg/MapServer/WMSServer?version=1.1.1&service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&version=1.1.1&)), missed out one of the separators (**&**), misspelled one of the parameters, or some combination of those things, because this is in effect what the error message is telling you.

I've looked at the service and as far as I can tell it is behaving correctly, but note that some of the layers are scale dependent (you have to zoom in to see them).

[Example GetMap request](http://service.salzburg.gv.at/ArcGIS/services/Geoland_WMS_Land_Salzburg/MapServer/WMSServer?REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&LAYERS=1&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&BGCOLOR=0xFFFFFF&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&SRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=12.7128052951991,47.3515227894406,13.2465257750068,47.8628789909326&WIDTH=883&HEIGHT=846&)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to complete the WMS query. It typically looks like a base URL, plus a service identifier (what service you want to request from that server - in your case WMS) and a request type (e.g. getcapabilities), as well as the version of the service (which you have). So the bit you add is:

```
?request=getcapabilities&service=WMS&version=1.1.1&
```

In QGIS, the part you put in as the URL is then:

```
http://service.salzburg.gv.at/ArcGIS/services/Geoland_WMS_Land_Salzburg/MapServer/WMSServer?request=getcapabilities&service=WMS&version=1.1.1&
```

That will give you back some XML, that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE WMT_MS_Capabilities SYSTEM "http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.1.1/WMS_MS_Capabilities.dtd">
<WMT_MS_Capabilities version="1.1.1">
  <Service>
    <Name>WMS</Name>
    <Title>Geoland WMS Land Salzburg</Title>
    <Abstract>Die Inhalte des Dienstes
"Geoland WMS Land Salzburg" werden mit größtmöglicher Sorgfalt recherchiert und aktualisiert. Fehler im
Bearbeitungsvorgang sind dennoch nicht auszuschließen. Die abfragbaren Informationen sind als Bürgerservice gedacht und
stellen keine Sachverständigeninformation dar. Es wird daher keine Gewähr für die Richtigkeit und Vollständigkeit der
angebotenen Informationen übernommen. Den hier bereitgestellten Informationen kommt keine Rechtsverbindlichkeit zu,
verbindlich sind ausschließlich die zugrunde liegenden Gesetzes- und Verordnungstexte samt zugehörigen
Plandarstellungen. Der Dienst "Geoland WMS Land Salzburg" wird kostenlos angeboten. Aus technischen Gründen kann kein
Anspruch auf uneingeschränkten Zugriff gewährleistet werden.</Abstract>
    <KeywordList><Keyword></Keyword></KeywordList>
    <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://service.salzburg.gv.at/ArcGIS/services/Geoland_WMS_Land_Salzburg/MapServer/WMSServer"/>
    <ContactInformation>
      <ContactPersonPrimary>
        <ContactPerson></ContactPerson>
        <ContactOrganization></ContactOrganization>
      </ContactPersonPrimary>
      <ContactPosition></ContactPosition>
      <ContactAddress>
        <AddressType></AddressType>
        <Address></Address>
        <City></City>
        <StateOrProvince></StateOrProvince>
        <PostCode></PostCode>
        <Country></Country>
      </ContactAddress>
      <ContactVoiceTelephone></ContactVoiceTelephone>
      <ContactFacsimileTelephone></ContactFacsimileTelephone>
      <ContactElectronicMailAddress></ContactElectronicMailAddress>
    </ContactInformation>
    <Fees></Fees>
    <AccessConstraints></AccessConstraints>
  </Service>
  <Capability>
    <Request>
      <GetCapabilities>
        <Format>application/vnd.ogc.wms_xml</Format>
        <DCPType>
          <HTTP><Get><OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://service.salzburg.gv.at/ArcGIS/services/Geoland_WMS_Land_Salzburg/MapServer/WMSServer"/></Get></HTTP>
        </DCPType>
      </GetCapabilities>
      <GetMap>
        <Format>image/bmp</Format>
        <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
        <Format>image/tiff</Format>
        <Format>image/png</Format>
        <Format>image/png8</Format>
        <Format>image/png24</Format>
        <Format>image/png32</Format>
        <Format>image/gif</Format>
        <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
        <DCPType>
          <HTTP><Get><OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://service.salzburg.gv.at/ArcGIS/services/Geoland_WMS_Land_Salzburg/MapServer/WMSServer"/></Get></HTTP>
        </DCPType>
      </GetMap>
      <GetFeatureInfo>
        <Format>application/vnd.ogc.wms_xml</Format>
        <Format>text/xml</Format>
        <Format>text/html</Format>
        <Format>text/plain</Format>
        <DCPType>
          <HTTP><Get><OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://service.salzburg.gv.at/ArcGIS/services/Geoland_WMS_Land_Salzburg/MapServer/WMSServer"/></Get></HTTP>
        </DCPType>
      </GetFeatureInfo>
    </Request>
    <Exception>
      <Format>application/vnd.ogc.se_xml</Format>
      <Format>application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage</Format>
      <Format>application/vnd.ogc.se_blank</Format>
    </Exception>
    <Layer>
    <Title>Layers</Title>
    <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
    <SRS>EPSG:31258</SRS>
    <SRS>EPSG:3416</SRS>
    <LatLonBoundingBox minx="11.149500" miny="46.527294" maxx="15.195845" maxy="48.879446"/>
    <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="289778.356250" miny="156293.748700" maxx="586633.018750" maxy="415667.595300"/>
    <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3416" minx="4456313.16316066" miny="2643024.28817785" maxx="4643461.54612034" maxy="2784177.40998335"/>
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>0</Name>
        <Title>Polygondecker</Title>
        <Abstract>Polygondecker</Abstract>
        <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:31258</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:3416</SRS>
        <LatLonBoundingBox minx="11.149500" miny="46.527294" maxx="15.195845" maxy="48.879446"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="289778.356250" miny="156293.748700" maxx="586633.018750" maxy="415667.595300"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3416" minx="4456313.16316066" miny="2643024.28817785" maxx="4643461.54612034" maxy="2784177.40998335"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>Polygondecker</Title>
        </Style>
      </Layer>
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>1</Name>
        <Title>Orientierungskarte</Title>
        <Abstract>Orientierungskarte</Abstract>
        <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:31258</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:3416</SRS>
        <LatLonBoundingBox minx="11.149500" miny="46.527294" maxx="15.195845" maxy="48.879446"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="289778.356250" miny="156293.748700" maxx="586633.018750" maxy="415667.595300"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3416" minx="4456313.16316066" miny="2643024.28817785" maxx="4643461.54612034" maxy="2784177.40998335"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>Orientierungskarte</Title>
        </Style>
        <ScaleHint min="0.000396" max="198.000000"></ScaleHint>
      </Layer>
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>2</Name>
        <Title>Flugjahr Laser</Title>
        <Abstract>Flugjahr Laser</Abstract>
        <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:31258</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:3416</SRS>
        <LatLonBoundingBox minx="11.149500" miny="46.527294" maxx="15.195845" maxy="48.879446"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="289778.356250" miny="156293.748700" maxx="586633.018750" maxy="415667.595300"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3416" minx="4456313.16316066" miny="2643024.28817785" maxx="4643461.54612034" maxy="2784177.40998335"/>       <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="360000.001200" miny="202499.960400" maxx="471256.660200" maxy="322801.840000"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>Flugjahr Laser</Title>
        </Style>
        <ScaleHint min="0.989604" max="9900.000000"></ScaleHint>
      </Layer>
      <Layer>
        <Name>3</Name>
        <Title>Orthofoto</Title>
        <Abstract>Orthofoto</Abstract>
        <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:31258</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:3416</SRS>
        <LatLonBoundingBox minx="11.149500" miny="46.527294" maxx="15.195845" maxy="48.879446"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="289778.356250" miny="156293.748700" maxx="586633.018750" maxy="415667.595300"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3416" minx="4456313.16316066" miny="2643024.28817785" maxx="4643461.54612034" maxy="2784177.40998335"/>        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="-15000.000000" miny="-12499.600000" maxx="502500.000000" maxy="325000.000000"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>Orthofoto</Title>
        </Style>
        <ScaleHint min="3.960000" max="7.920396"></ScaleHint>
      </Layer>
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>4</Name>
        <Title>Flugjahr Orthofoto</Title>
        <Abstract>Flugjahr Orthofoto</Abstract>
        <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:31258</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:3416</SRS>
        <LatLonBoundingBox minx="11.149500" miny="46.527294" maxx="15.195845" maxy="48.879446"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="289778.356250" miny="156293.748700" maxx="586633.018750" maxy="415667.595300"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3416" minx="4456313.16316066" miny="2643024.28817785" maxx="4643461.54612034" maxy="2784177.40998335"/>        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="350000.000000" miny="200000.000000" maxx="502500.000000" maxy="325000.000000"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>Flugjahr Orthofoto</Title>
        </Style>
        <ScaleHint min="3.960000" max="7.920396"></ScaleHint>
      </Layer>
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>5</Name>
        <Title>Vogelschutzgebiete</Title>
        <Abstract>Vogelschutzgebiete</Abstract>
        <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:31258</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:3416</SRS>
        <LatLonBoundingBox minx="11.149500" miny="46.527294" maxx="15.195845" maxy="48.879446"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="289778.356250" miny="156293.748700" maxx="586633.018750" maxy="415667.595300"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3416" minx="4456313.16316066" miny="2643024.28817785" maxx="4643461.54612034" maxy="2784177.40998335"/>        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="355213.187000" miny="208292.740000" maxx="467914.250000" maxy="322110.500000"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>Vogelschutzgebiete</Title>
        </Style>
        <ScaleHint min="0.792000" max="39.600000"></ScaleHint>
      </Layer>
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>6</Name>
        <Title>Habitat Richtlinie (PSCI)</Title>
        <Abstract>Habitat Richtlinie (PSCI)</Abstract>
        <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:31258</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:3416</SRS>
        <LatLonBoundingBox minx="11.149500" miny="46.527294" maxx="15.195845" maxy="48.879446"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="289778.356250" miny="156293.748700" maxx="586633.018750" maxy="415667.595300"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3416" minx="4456313.16316066" miny="2643024.28817785" maxx="4643461.54612034" maxy="2784177.40998335"/>        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="355213.187000" miny="208292.740000" maxx="496801.031000" maxy="317690.719000"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>Habitat Richtlinie (PSCI)</Title>
        </Style>
        <ScaleHint min="0.792000" max="39.600000"></ScaleHint>
      </Layer>
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>7</Name>
        <Title>Naturpark</Title>
        <Abstract>Naturpark</Abstract>
        <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:31258</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:3416</SRS>
        <LatLonBoundingBox minx="11.149500" miny="46.527294" maxx="15.195845" maxy="48.879446"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="289778.356250" miny="156293.748700" maxx="586633.018750" maxy="415667.595300"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3416" minx="4456313.16316066" miny="2643024.28817785" maxx="4643461.54612034" maxy="2784177.40998335"/>        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="405173.279000" miny="222684.047000" maxx="457918.875000" maxy="312906.560000"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>Naturpark</Title>
        </Style>
        <ScaleHint min="0.792000" max="39.600000"></ScaleHint>
      </Layer>
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>8</Name>
        <Title>Landschaftsschutzgebiet</Title>
        <Abstract>Landschaftsschutzgebiet</Abstract>
        <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:31258</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:3416</SRS>
        <LatLonBoundingBox minx="11.149500" miny="46.527294" maxx="15.195845" maxy="48.879446"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="289778.356250" miny="156293.748700" maxx="586633.018750" maxy="415667.595300"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3416" minx="4456313.16316066" miny="2643024.28817785" maxx="4643461.54612034" maxy="2784177.40998335"/>        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="354916.600000" miny="203242.203000" maxx="496801.031000" maxy="317699.875000"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>Landschaftsschutzgebiet</Title>
        </Style>
        <ScaleHint min="0.792000" max="39.600000"></ScaleHint>
      </Layer>
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>9</Name>
        <Title>Nationalpark</Title>
        <Abstract>Nationalpark</Abstract>
        <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:31258</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:3416</SRS>
        <LatLonBoundingBox minx="11.149500" miny="46.527294" maxx="15.195845" maxy="48.879446"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="289778.356250" miny="156293.748700" maxx="586633.018750" maxy="415667.595300"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3416" minx="4456313.16316066" miny="2643024.28817785" maxx="4643461.54612034" maxy="2784177.40998335"/>        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="355213.187000" miny="208292.740000" maxx="455673.211900" maxy="235598.000000"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>Nationalpark</Title>
        </Style>
        <ScaleHint min="0.792000" max="39.600000"></ScaleHint>
      </Layer>
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>10</Name>
        <Title>Naturschutzgebiet</Title>
        <Abstract>Naturschutzgebiet</Abstract>
        <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:31258</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:3416</SRS>
        <LatLonBoundingBox minx="11.149500" miny="46.527294" maxx="15.195845" maxy="48.879446"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="289778.356250" miny="156293.748700" maxx="586633.018750" maxy="415667.595300"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3416" minx="4456313.16316066" miny="2643024.28817785" maxx="4643461.54612034" maxy="2784177.40998335"/>        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="358688.249979" miny="200607.593764" maxx="493541.906169" maxy="322110.499989"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>Naturschutzgebiet</Title>
        </Style>
        <ScaleHint min="0.792000" max="39.600000"></ScaleHint>
      </Layer>
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>11</Name>
        <Title>geschuetzte Landschaftsteile</Title>
        <Abstract>geschuetzte Landschaftsteile</Abstract>
        <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:31258</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:3416</SRS>
        <LatLonBoundingBox minx="11.149500" miny="46.527294" maxx="15.195845" maxy="48.879446"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="289778.356250" miny="156293.748700" maxx="586633.018750" maxy="415667.595300"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3416" minx="4456313.16316066" miny="2643024.28817785" maxx="4643461.54612034" maxy="2784177.40998335"/>        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="365518.469000" miny="215665.500000" maxx="493367.313000" maxy="318524.156000"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>geschuetzte Landschaftsteile</Title>
        </Style>
        <ScaleHint min="0.792000" max="39.600000"></ScaleHint>
      </Layer>
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>12</Name>
        <Title>Landesstrasse B</Title>
        <Abstract>Landesstrasse B</Abstract>
        <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:31258</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:3416</SRS>
        <LatLonBoundingBox minx="11.149500" miny="46.527294" maxx="15.195845" maxy="48.879446"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="289778.356250" miny="156293.748700" maxx="586633.018750" maxy="415667.595300"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3416" minx="4456313.16316066" miny="2643024.28817785" maxx="4643461.54612034" maxy="2784177.40998335"/>        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="357487.527200" miny="204264.759300" maxx="497696.075100" maxy="322484.868300"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>Landesstrasse B</Title>
        </Style>
        <ScaleHint min="0.000396" max="39.600000"></ScaleHint>
      </Layer>
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>13</Name>
        <Title>Landesstrasse L</Title>
        <Abstract>Landesstrasse L</Abstract>
        <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:31258</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:3416</SRS>
        <LatLonBoundingBox minx="11.149500" miny="46.527294" maxx="15.195845" maxy="48.879446"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="289778.356250" miny="156293.748700" maxx="586633.018750" maxy="415667.595300"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3416" minx="4456313.16316066" miny="2643024.28817785" maxx="4643461.54612034" maxy="2784177.40998335"/>        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="357487.527200" miny="204264.759300" maxx="497696.075100" maxy="322484.868300"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>Landesstrasse L</Title>
        </Style>
        <ScaleHint min="0.000396" max="39.600000"></ScaleHint>
      </Layer>
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>14</Name>
        <Title>Autobahn</Title>
        <Abstract>Autobahn</Abstract>
        <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:31258</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:3416</SRS>
        <LatLonBoundingBox minx="11.149500" miny="46.527294" maxx="15.195845" maxy="48.879446"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="289778.356250" miny="156293.748700" maxx="586633.018750" maxy="415667.595300"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3416" minx="4456313.16316066" miny="2643024.28817785" maxx="4643461.54612034" maxy="2784177.40998335"/>        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="357487.527200" miny="204264.759300" maxx="497696.075100" maxy="322484.868300"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>Autobahn</Title>
        </Style>
        <ScaleHint min="0.000396" max="39.600000"></ScaleHint>
      </Layer>
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>15</Name>
        <Title>Radwanderroute</Title>
        <Abstract>Radwanderroute</Abstract>
        <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:31258</SRS>
        <LatLonBoundingBox minx="11.149500" miny="46.527294" maxx="15.195845" maxy="48.879446"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="289778.356250" miny="156293.748700" maxx="586633.018750" maxy="415667.595300"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3416" minx="4456313.16316066" miny="2643024.28817785" maxx="4643461.54612034" maxy="2784177.40998335"/>        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="357635.844341" miny="204209.073492" maxx="499299.867579" maxy="321840.618703"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>Radwanderroute</Title>
        </Style>
        <ScaleHint min="0.0" max="1.980396"></ScaleHint>
      </Layer>
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>16</Name>
        <Title>geonam</Title>
        <Abstract>geonam</Abstract>
        <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:31258</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:3416</SRS>
        <LatLonBoundingBox minx="11.149500" miny="46.527294" maxx="15.195845" maxy="48.879446"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="289778.356250" miny="156293.748700" maxx="586633.018750" maxy="415667.595300"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3416" minx="4456313.16316066" miny="2643024.28817785" maxx="4643461.54612034" maxy="2784177.40998335"/>        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="303271.750000" miny="168083.469000" maxx="573139.625000" maxy="403877.875000"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>geonam</Title>
        </Style>
        <ScaleHint min="0.000396" max="7.919604"></ScaleHint>
      </Layer>
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>17</Name>
        <Title>Politische Gemeinde</Title>
        <Abstract>Politische Gemeinde</Abstract>
        <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:31258</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:3416</SRS>
        <LatLonBoundingBox minx="11.149500" miny="46.527294" maxx="15.195845" maxy="48.879446"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="289778.356250" miny="156293.748700" maxx="586633.018750" maxy="415667.595300"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3416" minx="4456313.16316066" miny="2643024.28817785" maxx="4643461.54612034" maxy="2784177.40998335"/>        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="354916.600000" miny="200624.270000" maxx="500338.550000" maxy="322601.840000"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>Politische Gemeinde</Title>
        </Style>
        <ScaleHint min="7.920000" max="39.600000"></ScaleHint>
      </Layer>
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>18</Name>
        <Title>Politische Bezirke</Title>
        <Abstract>Politische Bezirke</Abstract>
        <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:31258</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:3416</SRS>
        <LatLonBoundingBox minx="11.149500" miny="46.527294" maxx="15.195845" maxy="48.879446"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="289778.356250" miny="156293.748700" maxx="586633.018750" maxy="415667.595300"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3416" minx="4456313.16316066" miny="2643024.28817785" maxx="4643461.54612034" maxy="2784177.40998335"/>        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="354916.600000" miny="200624.270000" maxx="500338.550000" maxy="322601.840000"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>Politische Bezirke</Title>
        </Style>
        <ScaleHint min="39.600396" max="99.000000"></ScaleHint>
      </Layer>
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>19</Name>
        <Title>NUTS 3 Regionen</Title>
        <Abstract>NUTS 3 Regionen</Abstract>
        <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:31258</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:3416</SRS>
        <LatLonBoundingBox minx="11.149500" miny="46.527294" maxx="15.195845" maxy="48.879446"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="289778.356250" miny="156293.748700" maxx="586633.018750" maxy="415667.595300"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3416" minx="4456313.16316066" miny="2643024.28817785" maxx="4643461.54612034" maxy="2784177.40998335"/>        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="354921.781370" miny="200620.937612" maxx="500324.656130" maxy="322525.968638"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>NUTS 3 Regionen</Title>
        </Style>
        <ScaleHint min="3.959604" max="Infinity"></ScaleHint>
      </Layer>
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>20</Name>
        <Title>Landesgrenze</Title>
        <Abstract>Landesgrenze</Abstract>
        <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:31258</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:3416</SRS>
        <LatLonBoundingBox minx="11.149500" miny="46.527294" maxx="15.195845" maxy="48.879446"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="289778.356250" miny="156293.748700" maxx="586633.018750" maxy="415667.595300"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3416" minx="4456313.16316066" miny="2643024.28817785" maxx="4643461.54612034" maxy="2784177.40998335"/>        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:31258" minx="354916.600000" miny="200624.270000" maxx="500338.550000" maxy="322601.840000"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>Landesgrenze</Title>
        </Style>
        <ScaleHint min="198.000396" max="297.000000"></ScaleHint>
      </Layer>
    </Layer>
  </Capability>
</WMT_MS_Capabilities>
```

You can see the layers, and choose which one(s) you want to load.

Comment: Thanks a loT, but the error still appears. With this link it works fine: http://service.salzburg.gv.at/ArcGIS/services/Schutzgebiete_Inspire_Land_Salzburg/MapServer/WMSServer?version=1.1.1. But with the others the error appears. I can see the layers and choose which one(s) I want to load, but then the error comes. Sometimes (i did not figure out when) a error "layers contain different numbers of styles... appears. thanks

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your issue. Please be specific about what you are trying (not use "the others" and "the error"), what you expect to see, and what happens instead. We can't see your screen, so you must describe it in detail so we can provide accurate help.

Comment: Sorry tried to formulate it more specific in the question.